# Android app crashed when minimized and rotated

Tags: android, android-fragments, crash, fragmentmanager

My app crashes in following case:

1. Minimize before being fully rendered(i.e., launch user action to start a fragment and in the meantime click Home key).
2. Then rotate the device
3. Then maximize the app.

However it works fine if I either wait long for it to finish rendering before minimizing, or don't rotate the device after minimizing.

I was trying to figure out what the system did when I rotated the app after having minimized it. There was no logs output for that.

I also have a `ViewPager` in the activity. I'm not sure if the `ViewPager` plays a role in the crash.

> #### The crash report looks like:

```
Caused by: java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: length=2; index=4
  at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.restoreAllState(FragmentManager.java:1750)
  at android.app.Activity.onCreate(Activity.java:943)
  at android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.onCreate(FragmentActivity.java:257)
  at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.onCreate(AppCompatActivity.java:58)
  at com.blackberry.emailviews.activity.SwipeableEmailActivity.onCreate(MyActivity.java:124)
  at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6034)
```

Comment: This tells you exactly what and where the problem is. What: java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException More specifically, you're trying to reference element of an array at index 4, whereas said array has only 2 elements. Where: MyActivity line 124. Check what's on that line.

Comment: That code is inside of FragmentManager class which is Android code.

Comment: Isn't the Activity trying to change its content while not in resumed state?
When the screen is rotated, the Activity is destroyed and re-created. If you keep the reference of the old Activity and try to change its content, it'll crash.
When you press Home while loading data and the Activity's state changes to paused and you try to change it, it'll crash too.
When you wait long enough for the Activity and the Fragment to be fully loaded, there is no problem. When you press Home or rotate, either one of the above situations may happen

Comment: Isn't there more log output in the stack trace before "android.app.Activity.performCreate..."?

Comment: at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1106)
                                                                        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2278)
                                                                        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2387)

Answer (score 0):

Have you put the `android:configChanges="orientation|screenSize"` for activity in your AndroidMAnifext.xml file.

Usage of PagerAdapter example :

public class CustomPagerAdapter extends PagerAdapter {

```
public static final String TAG = CustomPagerAdapter.class.getSimpleName();
private Context context;
private ArrayList<Object> data;
private LayoutInflater inflater;

public CustomPagerAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<Object> data)
{
    this.data = data;
    this.context = context;
    inflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
}

@Override
public Object instantiateItem(ViewGroup pager, final int curentItem)
{
    Log.d(TAG, "instantiateItem called for position " + curentItem);

    //Inflate
    final View localView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.home_news_slide, null);
    if(null!=localView){
        final Data currentData= (Data) this.data.get(curentItem);
        TextView title = (TextView)localView.findViewById(R.id.title_textview);
        TextView date = (TextView)localView.findViewById(R.id.date_textview);
        final ImageView imageView = (ImageView) localView.findViewById(R.id.home_slide_image);
        //Set
        title.setText(currentData.getTitle());
        date.setText(Util.dateParse((currentData.getDate())));
        imageView.setImageUrl(currentData.getArticleImage(), VolleyService.getInstance(context).getImageLoader());
        imageView.setDefaultImageResId(R.drawable.default_img);
        imageView.setErrorImageResId(R.drawable.default_img);
        //Event listener for Fragment switch
        localView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                //Open some activity
            }
        });
        pager.addView(localView,curentItem);
    }

    return localView;
}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    return data.size();
}

@Override
public boolean isViewFromObject(View view, Object object) {
    return view == object;
}

@Override
public void destroyItem(ViewGroup container, int position, Object object)
{
    container.removeView((View) object);
}
```

}

Comment: This crash may be caused by the use of commitAllowingStateLoss(). The situation might be very particular because we have a ViewPager. Any advice on what is the best way to deal with saving and restoring ViewPager when device rotates or is minimized?

Comment: For my case I extended the PagerAdapter class and implemented the destroyItem, isViewFromObject and instantiateItem methods which deals with your problem above. I can post the code example. So I needed this adapter in listview and it works and also it works standalone.

Comment: Hi @Kenan, can you please post your example? Thanks.